# How to save page in Firefox, Chrome, PhantomJS with selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I want to save a web site and download file into specific folder. How can I do it with webdriver?
In Chrome and Firefox I just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then select a folder to save the current website. Is there any way to do it in selenium webdriver? Can PhantomJS do it?

Comment: Do you want to save the current open webpage or the complete website?

Comment: you can check this out: [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

Comment: "Do you want to save the current open webpage or the complete website?" yes, I want to save it with specify name and folder

Comment: Abhijeet Vaikar i checkec HTTrack, I mean that When I open a website via "selenium webDriver" some time i want to save the web site in local to check content (like "Ctrl + S" in FireFox or Chrome) but I don't now how to set name and folder to save in Webdriver

Comment: I want to save a complete website like "Ctrl + S" in Chorme or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is that you cannot do this with the current features of selenium.

Why? The two available features from Selenium that are relevant for your needs are:

- taking screenshot
- and retrieving the html source of the page

However those won't match what is done with a Ctrl+S.

Comment: You can to execute JavaScript and get the current page HTML

Comment: Hi, the question is not about retrieving html of the current page but to simulate the ctrl+s behavior, which is doing more than retrieving the current page html. Ctrl+s will save resources of the page and generate a local folder tree.

Comment: Agree with thesmash. @Tooklkit, you should be the one who needs to read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Automate pressing Control S then switch to the save menu and save the html file. Here's how I did it with Python:

```
    driver.send_keys("u'\ue009'"+"s")
    driver.switch_to.window("Window_ID")
    driver.find_element_by_id("SAVE_button").click()
```

Use the inspect tool to find the Window name and the necessary Id's.

see: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.CONTROL

Comment: Could be that the API changed since the original post, but "send_keys" is not a method available on the webdriver object any longer.  It does exist either on elements in the page or on an ActionChain object.